# Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea what's wrong with the follow &sql select statement.  TABLE_PREFIX is perfectly fine.  If I echo `$content['content_id']` on the line before the $sql it returns the proper value.

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(release_date) FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."content WHERE content_id='".$content['content_id']."'";
$result= mysql_query($sql, $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['release_date'];
```

I've even tried specify `$content['content_id']` by replacing it with "2" which is a valid content_id. Why do I keep getting `Warning:  mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in...`?

Comment: show us what's in $db

Comment: You should be checking the value of `$result` after querying the database, if `$result` is `FALSE` you should check the output of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This means u have not connected to the MySql server before your query. Google `mysql_connect` Also, u want to move away from mysql_* functions and use mysqli_* functions or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use `$this->db` instead of `$db`.